# Gathering the correct amount of digits for numbers when text mining

Tags: r, function, grepl

I need to search for specific information within a set of documents that follows the same standard layout.

After I used `grep` to find the keywords in every document, I went on collecting the numbers or characters of interest.

One piece of data I have to collect is the *Total Power* that appears as following:

> TotalPower:  986559. (UoPow)

Since I had already correctly selected this excerpt, I created the following function that takes the characters between positions n and m, where n and m start counting up from right to left.

```
substrRight <- function(x, n,m){
 substr(x, nchar(x)-n+1, nchar(x)-m)
}
```

It's important to say that from the "**:**" to the number 986559, there are 2 spaces; and from the "**.**" to the "(", there's one space.

So I wrote:

```
TotalP = substrRight(myDf[i],17,9)        [1]
```

where `myDf` is a character vector with all the relevant observations.

Line [1], after I loop over all my observations, gives me the numbers I want, but I noticed that when the number was 986559, the result was 98655. It simply doesn't "see" 9 as the last number.

The code seems to work fine for the rest of the data. This number (986559) is indeed the highest number in the data and is the only one with order 10^5 of magnitude.

How can I make sure that I will gather all digits in every number?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Did you meant `stringr::str_extract(str1, "\\d+(?=.)")#[1] "986559"
`

Comment: Hey, @akrun, if you're asking if I meant to get "986559" as my answer, yes. Unfortunately, I don't understand the code you wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can extract the digits before a `.` by using regex lookaround

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(str1, "\\d+(?=\\.)")
#[1] "986559"
```

The `\\d+` indicates one or more digist followed by the regex lookaound `.`

Comment: Hey, @akrun, thank you; but I have another question. In the file I am getting my data from, the lines where I find TotalPower as something like this: 

AAAA:  XXXXXX. (ooooo)     BBBB:  YYYYYY. (ooooo)     TotalP:   986559. (ooooo) 

Running the piece of code you wrote, it starts gathering the digits after the first (, which will be XXXXXX. How can I make it get the number I want, ie, Total Power?

Comment: @MasonBeau Not clear about ur expected output.  Can you update your post,  I guess you wanted to extract all the instances, right?  In that case, use `str_extract_all` instead of `str_extract`

Comment: What I meant was from the line " AAAA: XXXXXX. (ooooo) BBBB: YYYYYY. (ooooo) TotalP: 986559. (ooooo)", where As, Bs, and o's are characters, I want to get the last number of three numbers. Iow, the output I want is "986559". But this number is the third number of the line. XXXXXX and YYYYYY are numbers that come before 986559.

Comment: @MasonBeau  If I use the string as `str2 <- "AAAA: XXXXXX. (ooooo) BBBB: YYYYYY. (ooooo) TotalP: 986559. (ooooo)"
;str_extract(str2, "\\d+(?=\\.)")
#[1] "986559"`

Comment: Oh, ok. Thank you, @akrun. I'll test this.